# Hi, I have to set a dynamic Date to replace hard coded value, I hace A flag in my table, how can I replace my hard coded value:

Tags: dynamic, tuples, mdx

I have to set a dynamic Date to replace hard coded value, I have A flag in my table, how can I replace my hard coded value with the flag:

```
(sum(
  PeriodsToDate(
     [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week],
     [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week].&[33]
  ),
  Measures].[sales]
  )
 )
```

I tried this but I have no value:

```
(sum(
    PeriodsToDate(
       [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week],
       [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week].&[All], ],[calendar].[WeekFlag].&[1]),  
       Measures].[sales]))
```

Do you have any Idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try using `currentmember` to generalise. You seem to have a lot of extra brackets!..

```
(sum(
    PeriodsToDate(
       [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week],
       [calendar].[hierarchy].[Week].CURRENTMEMBER
    )
    ,Measures].[sales])
)
```